# My Python function is ignoring one of the arguments

Tags: smtplib

I have created a python function to send email, it uses 2 arguments subject_line and my_message, but when running the function it is ignoring the subject_line argument.

Code below:

import smtplib

def send_email(subject_line, my_message):

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("smtp@mydomain.com", 25)

sender = "xyz@mydomain.com"

receivers = "xyz@mydomain.com"

message = """"From: From test <xyz@mydomain.com>
To: To Person <xyz@mydomain.comm>
Subject: {}

This is a test e-mail message {}
""".format(subject_line, my_message)

smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
```

send_email("My_subject", "Test Message")

This sends out an email with an empty subject line.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

referring to:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email-examples.html

I think you should use MIMEText:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText(my_message)

msg['Subject'] = subject_line
msg['From'] = sender 
msg['To'] = receivers 

smtpObj.send_message(msg)
```